# What is the difference between numpy.linalg.lstsq and scipy.linalg.lstsq?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, least-squares

`lstsq` tries to solve `Ax=b` minimizing `|b - Ax|`. Both scipy and numpy provide a `linalg.lstsq` function with a very similar interface. The documentation does not mention which kind of algorithm is used, neither for [scipy.linalg.lstsq](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.lstsq.html#scipy.linalg.lstsq) nor for [numpy.linalg.lstsq](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.lstsq.html#numpy.linalg.lstsq), but it seems to do pretty much the same.

The implementation seems to be different for [scipy.linalg.lstsq](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/2d1bd60e0330bb07880f8eab717e21ee17422245/scipy/linalg/basic.py#L537) and [numpy.linalg.lstsq](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/linalg/linalg.py#L1756). Both seem to use LAPACK, both algorithms seem to use a SVD.

Where is the difference? Which one should I use?

**Note:** do not confuse `linalg.lstsq` with `scipy.optimize.leastsq` which can solve also non-linear optimization problems.

Comment: Can you be more specific about the differences, at least as far as you can see from the respective Python codes?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

If I read the source code right (Numpy 1.8.2, Scipy 0.14.1
),  `numpy.linalg.lstsq()` uses the LAPACK routine `xGELSD` and `scipy.linalg.lstsq()` uses`xGELSS`.

The [LAPACK Manual Sec. 2.4](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/lug/node27.html#tabdrivellsq) states

> The subroutine xGELSD is significantly faster than its older counterpart xGELSS, especially for large problems, but may require somewhat more workspace depending on the matrix dimensions.

That means that Numpy is faster but uses more memory.

**Update August 2017:**

Scipy now uses xGELSD by default https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.lstsq.html

Answer (score 21):

### Numpy 1.13 - June 2017

As of Numpy 1.13 and Scipy 0.19, **both** [scipy.linalg.lstsq()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.lstsq.html) and [numpy.linalg.lstsq()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.lstsq.html) call by default the same LAPACK code DSGELD (see [LAPACK documentation](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/db/d6a/dgelsd_8f.html)).

However, a current important difference between the two function is in the adopted default RCOND LAPACK parameter (called `rcond` by Numpy and `cond` by Scipy), which defines the threshold for singular values.

Scipy uses a good and robust default threshold `RCOND=eps*max(A.shape)*S[0]`, where `S[0]` is the largest singular value of `A`, while Numpy uses a default threshold `RCOND=-1`, which corresponds to setting in LAPACK the threshold equal to the machine precision, regardless of the values of `A`.

Numpy's default approach is basically useless in realistic applications and will generally result in a very degenerate solution when `A` is nearly rank deficient, wasting the accuracy of the singular value decomposition SVD used by DSGELD. This implies that in Numpy the optional parameter `rcond` should be **always** used.

### Update: Numpy 1.14 - January 2018

I reported the incorrect default of `rcond` (see above Section) in [numpy.linalg.lstsq()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.lstsq.html) and the function now raises a `FutureWarning` in Numpy 1.14 (see [Future Changes](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/doc/release/1.14.0-notes.rst#future-changes)).

The future behaviour will be identical both in [scipy.linalg.lstsq()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.lstsq.html) and in [numpy.linalg.lstsq()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.lstsq.html). In other words, Scipy and Numpy will not only use the same LAPACK code, but also use the same defaults.

To start using the proper (i.e. future) default in Numpy 1.14, one should call [numpy.linalg.lstsq()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.lstsq.html) with an explicit `rcond=None`.