# Is the numpy.linalg.lstsq rcond parameter not working according to the description?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I am trying to use the least squares solution from numpy ([Description](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.lstsq.html)). According to the website to use the new default for the 'rcond' parameter: ''To silence the warning and use the new default, use rcond=None, to keep using the old behavior, use rcond=-1.''

With the rcond parameter set to None:

```
vector = np.linalg.lstsq(GA, FA, rcond = None)
```

It returns me an error:

```
TypeError: must be real number, not NoneType
```

Which does not happen when the parameter is taken away or set to -1.

I did some check and according to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29372559/what-is-the-difference-between-numpy-linalg-lstsq-and-scipy-linalg-lstsq) and one of the answers had an update stating that there were some recent changes on this method.

Then I would like to ask if someone else is having the same problem or if there is something as a typo on my line (Or something else I haven't thought about).

Kind Regards,
Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need NumPy >= 1.14. What version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

```
 x = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3])
 y = np.array([-1, 0.2, 0.9, 2.1])
 A = np.vstack([x, np.ones(len(x))]).T
 print(A)
 m, c = np.linalg.lstsq(A, y, rcond=1.e-10)[0]
 print (m,c)
# rcond must be a float. None as in the documentation 
# gives the "TypeError: a float is required"
```